# Unable to locate element to sendkeys C# WebDriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, browser-automation

I'm working with the following HTML:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="formRow">
    <td class="labelColumn">
        <span id="ctl00_MainContent_lblTemplate">Template</span>
    </td>
    <td class="fieldColumn">
        <div id="ctl00_MainContent_ddlTemplate" class="RadDropDownList RadDropDownList_Default" style="width:300px;" tabindex="0">
        <span class="rddlInner"><span class="rddlFakeInput">&lt;No Template&gt;</span><span class="rddlIcon"><!-- &nbsp; --></span></span><div class="rddlSlide" id="ctl00_MainContent_ddlTemplate_DropDown" style="display:none;">
        <div class="rddlPopup rddlPopup_Default">
        <ul class="rddlList">
        <li class="rddlItem  rddlItemSelected">&lt;No Template&gt;</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div><input id="ctl00_MainContent_ddlTemplate_ClientState" name="ctl00_MainContent_ddlTemplate_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
         <input name="ctl00$MainContent$Button8" type="button" id="ctl00_MainContent_Button8" class="invisible" style="width: 0px; height: 19px" value="Button">

    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="ctl00_MainContent_trCode" class="formRow">
    <td style="height: 3px" class="labelColumn">
        <span id="ctl00_MainContent_lblCode">Code</span>
    </td>
    <td style="height: 3px" class="fieldColumn">
        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtCode" type="text" maxlength="10" id="ctl00_MainContent_txtCode" onkeypress="return UpperCaseFieldKeyPress(this,event);" style="width:110px;">&nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="formRow">
    <td style="height: 20px" class="labelColumn">
        <span id="ctl00_MainContent_lblName" class=" compulsory">Name</span>
    </td>
    <td style="height: 20px" class="fieldColumn">
        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtName" type="text" maxlength="40" id="ctl00_MainContent_txtName" style="width:350px;">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="ctl00_MainContent_trDescription" class="formRow">
    <td class="labelColumn">
        <span id="ctl00_MainContent_lblDescription">Description</span>&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td class="fieldColumn">
        <textarea name="ctl00$MainContent$txtDescription" rows="2" cols="20" id="ctl00_MainContent_txtDescription" onkeypress="return CheckFieldLengthKeyPress(this, event, 80);" style="height:48px;width:350px;"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="ctl00_MainContent_trCustomer" class="formRow">
    <td class="labelColumn">
        <span id="ctl00_MainContent_lblCustomer">Customer</span>
    </td>
    <td class="fieldColumn">
        <span class="RadAjaxPanel" id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_aeCustomerPanelPanel"><div id="ctl00_MainContent_aeCustomerPanel">

        <span class="RadAjaxPanel" id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_txtCustomerCodePanel"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtCustomerCode" type="text" maxlength="10" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$txtCustomerCode\',\'\')', 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="ctl00_MainContent_txtCustomerCode" style="width:128px;"></span>
        <span id="ctl00_MainContent_btnFindCustomer_Wrapper" class="LookupImageButtonWrapper">
        <input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnFindCustomer" id="ctl00_MainContent_btnFindCustomer" class="LookupImageButton" src="../Icons/GetIcon.aspx?n=clearpixel&amp;s=1" onclick="javascript:FindCustomer(''); return false;" style="border-width:0px;">&nbsp;
        </span>
        <span id="ctl00_MainContent_btnAddMultiCustomers_Wrapper" class="MultipleButtonWrapper">
        <input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnMultiCustomers" id="ctl00_MainContent_btnMultiCustomers" title="Multiple customers" class="AbsMiddle" src="../Icons/16x16/addline.gif" onclick="javascript:EditCustomers(23);return false;" style="border-width:0px;">&nbsp;
        </span>
        <span style="overflow: hidden">
        <span id="ctl00_MainContent_lblCustomerName" class="labelText"></span>
        </span>

        </div><span class="RadAjaxPanel" id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_txtCustomerCodePanel"></span></span>

    </td>
</tr>
```

I'm specifically trying to locate the following elements with the ultimate goal of inputting text using sendkeys:

```
<td style="height: 20px" class="fieldColumn">
   <input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtName" type="text" maxlength="40" id="ctl00_MainContent_txtName" style="width:350px;">
</td>
```

and

```
 <td style="height: 3px" class="fieldColumn">
   <input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtCode" type="text" maxlength="10" id="ctl00_MainContent_txtCode" onkeypress="return UpperCaseFieldKeyPress(this,event);" style="width:110px;">&nbsp;
 </td>
```

So far I have tried the following approaches but have been unable to locate either of them:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_txtCode"));
```

throwing: `Message: "no such element: Unable to locate element:`

```
driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$MainContent$txtCode"));
```

throwing: `Message: "no such element: Unable to locate element:`

```
driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("fieldColumn"));
```

I realize this would not find the element I need but thought if I find by class name I could insert a contains clause - this also throws: throwing: `Message: "no such element: Unable to locate element:`

I can find `TagName("tr")` & `TagName("td")` but when I attempt to create a list of all rows using the Id of the table I also get:

`Message: "no such element: Unable to locate element:`

I have found some joy identifying the `TagName("tbody")` however the same table has multiple "tbody" tags - for this I am using

```
driver.FindElement((By.TagName("tbody")));
```

but this always gives me the first `tbody` which is not the one I want.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please check iframe present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements were indeed in an iframe, managed to access the iframe using,

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0)
```

Following this I could locate the elements I needed no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use css selector;

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=\"ctl00$MainContent$txtName\"]"));
```